# Re: Google SDK IOS Attribution Text

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

According to Google IOS SDK documentation, I am suppose to call GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo to display the attribution text.

I have a (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil in my infoViewController where I call the [GMServices openSourceLicenseInfo], but nothing is appearing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

+[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo] returns an NSString.  You have to display the string yourself somewhere within the UI of your app.